# Подсчет процента от общей суммы в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Данна таблица, необходимо с помощь оконной функции необходимо показать, какой процент от общей зарплаты по отделу(job) составляет зарплата каждого сотрудника

```
   name    |   job   | salary 
-----------+---------+--------
 Joe       | develop |   2500
 Connor    | manager |   3500
 Callum    | sales   |   1400
 Kyle      | develop |   1200
 Jacob     | sales   |    950
 John      | manager |   1300
```

Должно выйти вот так

```
   name    |   job   | salary | percent 
-----------+---------+--------+---------
 Joe       | develop |   2500 |    67%
 Kyle      | develop |   1200 |    33%
 Connor    | manager |   3500 |    73%
 John      | manager |   1300 |    27%
 Callum    | sales   |   1400 |    59%
 Jacob     | sales   |    950 |    41%
```

Мой вариант, но ничего не работает.

```
 SELECT name, job, salary, percent(sum(salary)*100/salary)
 OVER (PARTITION BY job) FROM emp;
```

Comment: функции percent не существует. вы видимо имели ввиду `(sum(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY job)) *100/salary as percent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT name, job, salary, salary / (sum(salary) OVER (partition BY job)) * 100
 FROM   emp
```